# Hibernate is giving me the old object while fetching for max id

Tags: c#, hibernate

I am using hibernate with spring mvc.
I am using single session factory instance/thread for the entire web application.
I am using session object on per request based.

I am fetching the max id ,it is giving me the correct value and then i am updating something in the table with the same incremented max id.

The problem i am facing is that when i fetching the max id again it is giving me the same previous max id but not the updated one.

tricky part is that after the exception have come if i try it again then it is giving me the correct max id value.

note:- on every max id fetching i am opening a new session object and then closing it at last.

This is my code:-

```
public static void prepareLogin(HttpServletRequest request,
            String loggedUser, int loggedUserType, int loggedUserId) {


        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();

        // fetching the max id from login manager table to update the login and
        // logout or various details
        int loginManagerMaxIdInt = 0;
        Criteria c2 = session.createCriteria(LoginManager.class);
        c2.addOrder(Order.desc("id"));
        c2.setMaxResults(1);
        LoginManager loginManager = (LoginManager) c2.uniqueResult();
        if (loginManager != null) {
            loginManagerMaxIdInt = loginManager.getId();
        }

        loginManagerMaxIdInt++;

        System.out.println("logManId: " + loginManagerMaxIdInt);

        // preparing the new loginManager object to be stored in the DB
        LoginManager newLoginManager = new LoginManager();
        newLoginManager.setId(loginManagerMaxIdInt);
        newLoginManager.setUserId(loggedUserId);
        newLoginManager.setLoginTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        UserTypeMaster userTypeMaster = new UserTypeMaster();
        userTypeMaster.setId(loggedUserType);
        newLoginManager.setUserTypeMaster(userTypeMaster);

        // binding the username, userType and loginManager id value to
        // the session
        // object
        request.getSession().setAttribute("loggedUser", loggedUser);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("loggedUserType", loggedUserType);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("loggedLoginManagerId",
                loginManagerMaxIdInt);

        // finally saving it and commiting
        session.save(newLoginManager);
        tr.commit();
        session.close();

    }
```

2nd edit:
After saving this object i am updating the same object in the db with the following code:

```
// logout method to logout the user by just invalidating the session object
// because in that session object only all important object are bind
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView logout(HttpServletRequest request) {

    //new session
    Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
    //begin transaction logout time updation
    Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();

    //fetching the login_Manager row from login_manager table for current 
    //logged User 
    LoginManager loginManager = (LoginManager) session.get(
            LoginManager.class,
            Utility.getLoggedLoginManagerId(request));

    //changing the logut time to current time in the fetched object
    loginManager.setLogoutTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    //updating the same object to the db
    session.update(loginManager);
    tr.commit();

    //invalidating the sessin object 
    request.getSession().invalidate();

    //finally closing the session
    session.close();
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + "login");
}
```

note: if i don't go through this second method then my code is working fine. i.e if i only save new object then everything is fine and max id is also fetching perfectly.

please help me regarding this.

Comment: Something is wrong with your code.

Comment: let me post my code

Comment: You haven't posted code that reads and increments the value. Where's is the rest of the code?

Comment: In the above code where i am using Criteria , i am reading the max id there and then incrementing the same retrieved value by loginManagerMaxIdInt++;

Comment: Yes, I can see that. But the prooblem is that when reading the max elsewhere, you're not getting what you expect. And you haven't posted that code.

Comment: i am reading the max again from this method only. as this method is to save the user login and logout details. So every time a user is logged , this method is call to save his/her login and logout details but after updating the table the next max id fetch is giving me this error:

Comment: You're comletely missing the point, once again. We can't find bugs in your code without seeing your code. The code matters. Just because you *want* your code to do something doesn't mean that it does.

Comment: please so to my updated post.. may be it will help

Comment: Okay finally got the answer. i added this to my configuration file <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</property> and now everything is fine. Sorry for my Bad questioning skills.

Comment: This is not the answer. This changes the isolation level. Had you posted the code before, I would have noticed you were using Spring, but still dealing with session and transaction management by yourself, programmatically (and probably in a wrong way), instead of letting Spring handle that, correctly, for you, and declaratively. This would not only make your code correct, but also much simpler and safer. Read the Spring documentation on how to integrate Hibernate, or better, JPA.

Comment: Shivam....you need to check your Hibernate settings for cache scenarios.  I remember other Dependency Injection frameworks, having a cache setting for each data model.  This basically, allows a developer to set whether to actively/proactively cache the data for speed of service.  In some scenario, this caching causes it to fail to refresh on Save/Commit actions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all sorry for my Bad questioning in this post.

The problem was related to this `<property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</property>`.

I added the above code in my configuration file and now everything is fine.

Answer (score -1):

Read about session flush, it synchronizes session data with database. If your session is not synchronized you won't see updated data.

Example: flush session BEFORE commiting/updating rows, you won't see expected result, however next flush should do the trick (synchronize session with database).

After exception you are opening a new session with actual state of database, that's why it works.

Comment: can you please share the recomended article for the same

Comment: i solved it by using <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</property, still thanks for suggestion.